# Odd sytax error in python: Invalid Syntax

Tags: python, syntax

So for whatever reason I keep getting a syntax error and I can't seem to figure out why. When I comment out the line that is giving me the error it propagates through, but when I put the troublesome bit in a new file it carries through and I'm not seeing anything wrong above or below in all of the code syntactically.

```
def removeBlock(pos, blocks):
    return blocks[pos] -= 1
def addBlock(pos, blocks):
    return blocks[pos] += 1
def left(pos):
    return pos -= 1
def right(pos):
    return pos += 1
def done():
    return "quit"

actions = {
    "P": removeBlock,
    "D": addBlock,
    "L": left,
    "R": right,
    "X": done
}
```

The error is this:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

it appears on the second line of this code.

Comment: You cannot return an `assignment operation` like `return blocks[pos] -= 1`.
Either return `return blocks[pos]-1` or use this `blocks[pos] -= 1` then `return blocks[pos]`.

Comment: I see you using the same kind of return statements. Please change it in all the functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Python `-=` operator does not give a return value.  Also for `+=` etc.

Try:

```
def removeBlock(pos, blocks):
    blocks[pos] -= 1
    return blocks[pos]
```

Or did you mean to not change the block?

```
def removeBlock(pos, blocks):
    return blocks[pos] - 1
```

Comment: i have tried that with the two lines in question that do that and move the blocks to be the return the but that just makes the error propagate further down all the way to where i declare pos = 0 in the larger code

Comment: @user3630096 - you will have to fix all `return something -=` (and +=).  I can't see `pos = 0` in your posted code.

Comment: for this snippet of code it just goes and moves the syntax problem down to the return pos -= 1

Comment: @user3630096 - yes, you need to fix all occurrences of this issue in your code.  I was only explaining what is incorrect.

Comment: Okay i figured it out im blind sorry

Comment: yea thought i was able to augment values in the return but i guess you cant in python

Comment: yea i fixed it im just not sure how to mark this as resolved

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return an assignment operation like `return blocks[pos] -= 1`. Either return `return blocks[pos]-1` or use this `blocks[pos] -= 1` then `return blocks[pos]`

Please try this:

```
def removeBlock(pos, blocks):
    blocks[pos] -= 1
    return blocks[pos]
def addBlock(pos, blocks):
    blocks[pos] += 1
    return blocks[pos]
def left(pos):
    pos -= 1
    return pos
def right(pos):
    pos += 1
    return pos
def done():
    return "quit"

actions = {
    "P": removeBlock,
    "D": addBlock,
    "L": left,
    "R": right,
    "X": done
}
```